# Is there any provision to use my java class in every android project

Tags: java, android-studio

I have developed my own java class in Android Stuido and I want to use it in my every project. Is there any provision to do so.

Can anyone suggest me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is

Answer (score 0):

You may pack your Java classes as a `.jar` library, then add this library in your Android project.

For "use it in my every project", you may have to modify the Android Studio new project template, which locates in `<AndroidStudioInstallDir>/plugins/android/lib/templates`. In my opinion, it is not recommended, it's better to add it manually inside every of your projects.

Besides, your Java classes should not use any packages / classes that is inside Java but not in Android, for example `javax.sound.midi`, or you will have to make a porting by yourself.